# 2sxc version 11.21.1 Broke DNN version 9.1.1. How Do I Rollback

Tags: 2sxc

I had to remove Tosic Dll's to get the server to boot. Tried restoring old Dll's; (I made a backup) and Desktop Modules files. I have tried to install an older package: that resulted an error message saying *newer version installed*.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Given the details you've detailed so far; the install and then manually changing/deleting things "under the hood" - I am pretty sure the only way forward is to restore from a backup from before you installed 2sxc.

Dnn and the modules/extensions have no concept of undo or rollback from installs or upgrades.

Comment: I attempted to solve the Tiny MCE text editor expired error & when just changing config didn't work, I installed new version of 2Sxc and it broke it for anyone else that happens here

Comment: Rolling back is actually very easy, because we almost never change the DB on updates (last time was ca. 2 years ago).

Answer (score 0):

To rollback an unfortunate upgrade, just do this:

1. In DNN go to the Extensions and set the version of "Content" and "App" down to a version before the version you want to go back to.

See checklist: https://azing.org/2sxc/r/6z3lel3k